# A question about the positive definite function

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Definition 2.5.6.** A function $\phi:\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is said to be *positive definite* if the matrix$$[\phi(s^{-1}t)]_{s,t\in F}\in M_{F}(\mathbb{C})$$
is positive for every finite set $F\subset \Gamma$. ($\Gamma$ is a group here.)

$\qquad$The *full group* C*-algebra of $\Gamma$, denoted $C^{*}(\Gamma)$, is  the completion of $\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ with respect to the norm
$$\|x\|_{u}=\sup\limits_{\large{\pi}}\|\pi(x)\|,$$
where the supremum is taken over all (cyclic) *-representations $\pi: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\rightarrow B(H)$.

**My question is: If we assume $\Gamma$ is countable. Then $C^{*}(\Gamma)$ has a faithful state $\phi$? Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $F=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$. Let $\bar s=(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$. Then, as a positive functional is completely positive, 
$$
0\leq\phi^{(n)}(\bar s^*\bar s)=[\phi(s^{-1}t)]_{s,t\in F}
$$

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I also hope to know why there exists a faithful state on $C^{*}(\Gamma).$

Comment: It is a standard fact that every separable C$^*$-algebra has a faithful state.

Comment: Er....Oh, thanks.....